# Inserción en BD y envió de correo simultaneo

Tags: php, email

Realizo un modulo de tickets desde una pagina web, pero lo que quiero hacer es que mis usuarios llenen ese formulario, que los mismos datos se inserten en mi BD y a su vez llegue un correo, tanto al usuario que lo registro como al administrador, con los registros que se insertaron. Mi BD la modele de forma en que se insertaran por ID (llaves foraneas) y las descripciones las contiene las tablas de donde vienen la llaves que encimo.

Mi duda es... ¿Se puede realizar eso en un formulario PHP?

**Formulario PHP**

```html
<?php
    $priorities =mysqli_query($con, "select * from priority");
 $turns =mysqli_query($con, "select * from turn");
 $areas =mysqli_query($con, "select * from area");
    $statuses =mysqli_query($con, "select * from status");
    $kinds =mysqli_query($con, "select * from kind");
    $categories =mysqli_query($con, "select * from category");
 
?>

    <div> <!-- Modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg-add"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Agregar Ticket</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg-add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Tickets</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask" method="post" id="add" name="add">
                        <div id="result"></div>
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Tipo
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="kind_id" >
                                      <?php foreach($kinds as $p):?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Titulo<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Descripción <span class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <textarea name="description" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Seguimiento de Proceso
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <textarea name="process_1" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="Seguimiento de Proceso"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Fin de Proceso
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                              <textarea name="process_2" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"  placeholder="Fin de Proceso"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Area
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="area_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                      <?php foreach($areas as $p):?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
                       
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Categoria
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="category_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                      <?php foreach($categories as $p):?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                      <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Prioridad</span>
       </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="priority_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                  <?php foreach($priorities as $p):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Turno<span class="required">*</label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="turn_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                  <?php foreach($turns as $p):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="first-name">Estado
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control" name="status_id" >
                                    <option selected="" value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
                                  <?php foreach($statuses as $p):?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>"><?php echo $p['name']; ?></option>
                                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
      
      
      
                        <div class="ln_solid"></div>
      
      
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                              <button id="save_data" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>  

      
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /Modal -->
```

**PHP para inserción de datos**

```html
<?php 
 session_start();
 /*Inicia validacion del lado del servidor*/
 if (empty($_POST['title'])) {
           $errors[] = "Titulo vacío";
        } else if (empty($_POST['description'])){
   $errors[] = "Description vacío";
  } else if (
   !empty($_POST['title']) &&
   !empty($_POST['description'])
  ){


  include "../config/config.php";//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos

  $title = $_POST["title"];
  $description = $_POST["description"];
  $process_1 = $_POST["process_1"];
  $process_2 = $_POST["process_2"];
  $description = $_POST["description"];
  $category_id = $_POST["category_id"];
  $priority_id = $_POST["priority_id"];
  $turn_id = $_POST["turn_id"];
  $area_id = $_POST["area_id"];
  $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
  $status_id = $_POST["status_id"];
  $kind_id = $_POST["kind_id"];
  $created_at="NOW()";

  // $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

  $sql="insert into ticket (title,description,process_1,process_2,category_id,priority_id,turn_id,area_id,user_id,status_id,kind_id,created_at) value (\"$title\",\"$description\", \"$process_1\",\"$process_2\",\"$category_id\",$priority_id,$turn_id,$area_id,$user_id,$status_id,$kind_id,$created_at)";

  $query_new_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   if ($query_new_insert){
    $messages[] = "Tu ticket ha sido ingresado satisfactoriamente.";
   } else{
    $errors []= "Lo siento algo ha salido mal intenta nuevamente.".mysqli_error($con);
   }
  } else {
   $errors []= "Error desconocido.";
  }
  
  if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages)){
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) {
         echo $message;
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <?php
   }

?>
```

**Correo (Ejemplo)**

```html
<?php
 $mensaje="";
 if(isset($_POST["envio"])){
   include("php/envioCorreo.php");
   $email = new email("Soporte Tecnico","oscar.soporte.pruebas@gmail.com","oscarmanzano1993");
   $email->agregar($_POST["email"],$_POST["nombre"],$_POST["asunto"]);
      
   if ($email->enviar('Reporte de Falla',$contenido_html)){
       
     $mensaje= 'Mensaje enviado';
       
   }else{
         
      $mensaje= 'El mensaje no se pudo enviar';
      $email->ErrorInfo;
   }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Correo</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
     <!----<div id="logo"><img src="logo-php.png"/></div>!--->
    </header>
    <div id="pagina">
     <section>
         <div>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="envio">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                             <label for="email">Email</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="ejemplo@dominio.com" autofocus maxlength="50" size="20">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Tu nombre" autofocus maxlength="50" size="20">
                               
                            </td>
       
       
       
       <td>
                             <label for="asunto">asunto</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                             <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="Tu comentario" autofocus maxlength="50" size="20">
                              
          <input name="envio" value="si" hidden="hidden">
                            </td>
       
       
       
                            <td>
                             <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
             </form>
            </div>
            <?php
    echo $mensaje;
   ?>
        </section>
        <aside>
        
        </aside>
    </div>
    <footer>
    
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Función de envio correo**

```html
?php
require ('class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php");

class Email  extends PHPMailer{

    //datos de remitente
    var $tu_email;
    var $tu_nombre;
    var $tu_password;

    /**
 * Constructor de clase
 */
    public function __construct($tu_nombre,$tu_email,$tu_password)
    {
      //configuracion general
     $this->IsSMTP(); // protocolo de transferencia de correo
     $this->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Servidor GMAIL
     $this->Port = 465; //puerto
     $this->SMTPAuth = true; // Habilitar la autenticación SMTP
     $this->Username = $this->tu_email=$tu_email;
     $this->Password = $this->tu_password=$tu_password;
     $this->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  //habilita la encriptacion SSL
     //remitente
     $this->From = $this->tu_email;
     $this->FromName = $this->tu_nombre=$tu_nombre;
    $this->CharSet='UTF8';
    }

    /**
 * Metodo encargado del envio del e-mail
 */
    public function enviar($asunto , $contenido)
    {
      //$this->AddAddress($para,$nombre );  // Correo y nombre a quien se envia
    //$this->addCC("harold-c-m@hotmail.com",'Harold Campo Morales');
    //$this->addBCC("harold-c-m@hotmail.com",'Harold Campo Morales'); 
       $this->WordWrap = 50; // Ajuste de texto
       $this->IsHTML(true); //establece formato HTML para el contenido
       $this->Subject =$asunto;
       $this->Body    =  $contenido; //contenido con etiquetas HTML
       $this->AltBody =  strip_tags($contenido); //Contenido para servidores que no aceptan HTML
    //$this->addAttachment("archivoadjunto.pdf",'Prueba 1.pdf');
    //$this->addAttachment("archivoadjunto.pdf",'Prueba 2.pdf');
       //envio de e-mail y retorno de resultado
       return $this->Send() ;
   }
   public function agregar($correo,$nombre = ''){
    $this->addAddress($correo,$nombre);
 }

}//--> fin clase
 
 $contenido_html =  "<div>
       <p style='color:#F00'>
        Prueba realizada correctamente<strong><br>Esto en negrita.</strong><br>Cargando Imagen<br>
       </p>
       <img style='width:500px;height:300px; margin:0 auto;' src='https://gun.io/static/uploads/HTML%3ACSS3.jpg'/>
       <p>Seguimos escribiendo...</p>
         </div>";
?>
```

Comment: Si lo he entendido bien la respuesta es sí, se puede hacer lo que comentas con PHP. Pero sin más información y código de lo que tienes hasta ahora es difícil poder orientarte más.

Comment: @Ferni Disculpa ¿tendrás algún ejemplo que me pueda guiar para realizar lo que comento?

Comment: Tendrías que mostrar que tienes hasta ahora para poder orientarte.

Comment: @Ferni si claro te lo agradecería mucho, el formulario php es donde se ingresan mis datos, lo del correo es un formato de prueba (con otros datos) . Te inserto mis archivos y agradecería mucho tu ayuda

Comment: @Ferni Listo ya agregue los codigos, los primeros dos hacen referencia a mi fomulario los dos ultimos son del correo electronico pero son una prueba (con otros datos fuera del formulario) pero si envia el correo electronico. En verdad te agradeceria mucho si me pudieras orientar.